# Definite integral of $\int_{-x}^{\infty} dz e^{-z^2/2} \sqrt{x+z}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, gaussian-integral

Is there a way to calculate the definite integral for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^+$:
$$f_\sigma(x)=\int_{-x/\sigma}^{\infty} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \sqrt{x+\sigma z} =\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-(z-x)^2/\left(2\sigma^2\right)} \sqrt{z} $$

The regular approaches (i.e. Gamma integrals) work only for $x=0$. Any result in terms of well-known functions is, of course, acceptable.

Comment: I see no reason to think this is elementary.

Comment: Mathematica also gives a result: $\int\limits_{-\frac{x}{\sigma }}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \sqrt{x+\sigma  z}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} \, dz=\int\limits_0^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{z}\ e^{-\frac{(z-x)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi  \sigma ^2}} \, dz=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 \sigma ^2}} \left(x^2 \left(I_{\frac{5}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4 \sigma ^2}\right)-I_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4 \sigma ^2}\right)\right)+\left(2 \sigma ^2+x^2\right) I_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4 \sigma ^2}\right)-x^2 I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4 \sigma ^2}\right)\right)}{4 \sigma  \sqrt{-x}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing the change of variables $z = \sigma t$ in
$$
f_\sigma  (x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } \sigma }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\sqrt z \exp \left( { - \frac{{(z - x)^2 }}{{2\sigma ^2 }}} \right){\rm d}z} 
$$
yields
$$
f_\sigma  (x) = \sqrt {\frac{\sigma }{{2\pi }}} \exp \left( { - \frac{{x^2 }}{{2\sigma ^2 }}} \right)\int_0^{ + \infty } {\sqrt t \exp \left( { - \frac{{t^2 }}{2} + \frac{x}{\sigma }t} \right){\rm d}t} .
$$
By [$(12.5.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/12.5.E1)
$$
f_\sigma  (x) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{\sigma }{2}} \exp \left( { - \frac{{x^2 }}{{4\sigma ^2 }}} \right)U\!\left( {1, - \frac{x}{\sigma }} \right),
$$
where $U(a,z)$ is the [parabolic cylinder function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.2).